# How to make multiple click by using Angular e2e?

Tags: angularjs, click, selection, slickgrid

I'm writing an E2E tests where I'm using grid.
While I'm trying to make a single selection with the grid, it works fine.

```
element('#wrapped_grid .item-id-2 .slick-cell').click();
```

But I couldn't figure out how to simulate a multiple selection, (combination of click + ctrl key)

Any Ideas would be very appreciated !

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't of a way to simulate what you asked, consider "bypassing" the UI to simulate multiple selection directly on the controller.
In other words, directly invoke the method on the controller that would have handled the user's multi select.